# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, class

I got this error, i cant figure whats problem. My code is

```
class Example{
     public function get_lang()
        {
            $jezik = get_option('jezik');
                     switch ($jezik ) {
                         case $jezik == 'rs_RS':
                         $drzava = 'NazivSrb';
                         break;
                         case $jezik == 'ro_RO':
                         $drzava = 'NazivRo';
                         break;
                         case $jezik == 'uk_UK':
                         $drzava = 'NazivRu';
                         break;
                    }
            return $drzava;        
        }

    static public function ExecuteSql($where_criteria=NULL) {
            global $wpdb;

                   $drzva = $this->get_lang();

            $upit = "
                            SELECT ID, Naziv, $drzava, PhoneCode, Kod
                    FROM wp_drzava";
            if ($where_criteria)
                $upit .=" WHERE ". $where_criteria ;
            $upit .= " GROUP BY Kod";
            //echo $upit;
            return $wpdb->get_results($upit);
        }

{
```

Basically I try to use get_lang method return value, and save it to variable in other method, and pass it to query.
But i get an error in this line

```
$drzva = $this->get_lang();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$this` inside `static` method.. use `self` keyword if you want to use same class  method inside `static` method

```
self::get_lang();
```

**EDIT:** `get_lang()` should static method, if you are not using class properties inside method.

Comment: In this case, get_lang() should be static.

Comment: you can call non static method like `self::callmethod` while another method (`get_lang()`) not used `$this` inside method. static method is independent, you can call without create class object

Comment: get_lang() static method is accessible via  public ExecuteSql method, self:: will also work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$this` in a static public function (`$this` does not exist in it).

To fix this, use:

```
$example = new Example;
$drzva = $example->get_lang();
```